# How to get Payer_id back in our Mobile App

Tags: paypal

We have integrated the PayPal REST APIs in our app. The user redirects to the approval link after we get the payment created response. Now after approval, how do we redirect user back to our app with the payer id?

Answer (score 0):

Use [a deeplink URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_deep_linking) to redirect back to the app.